# Arduino multiple device connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, android-bluetooth

I am making an Android Bluetooth app which will send and receive data from 2 Arduino devices simultaneously.
I am able to connect either one of the devices (sender or receiver), but I cannot connect to both of them and send and receive data at the same time.

Any link, any reference app, any documentation would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

NOT SURE you can connect with 2 devices at the same time. you might
connect to one and disconnect and do the same with the second.
i'm trying to do the same things with 2 arduino. but at this time i can connect
to one arduino, but i don't know how to disconnect .
i'm using " Androidapi.JNI.BluetoothAdapter.hpp"? 
how do you disconnect your sock??